# Как в Materialize CSS поменять цвет radio кнопки?

Tags: html, css, css3, html-form, materialize-css

Есть код:

```html
<h5>Выравнивание заголовка</h5>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="alignHeader" value="center">
    <span>По центру</span>
</label>
<br>
<label>
    <input type="radio" checked name="alignHeader" value="left">
    <span>По левому краю</span>
</label>
<br>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="alignHeader" value="right">
    <span>По правому краю</span>
</label>
```

Выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как с помощью классов Materialize CSS поменять цвет именно для radio кнопки, когда она нажата. То есть мне нужен не тёмно-бирюзовый цвет, а зелёный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить следующий код в Ваш CSS-файл:

```
input[type="radio"].filled-in:checked + span:not(.lever) {
  border-color: #4CAF50;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```